# jquery datepicker: Enable specific date pattern

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I have a specific need in my project where I should enable only 1st and the 15th of every month in the jquery date picker. I have seen several solutions that is based on an array of dates, but that is not going to work for me. Is there a way a pattern can be applied?

@mtndesign - For your response/question on why I cannot use an array:
The datepicker should always (all past, current and future months & years) show only 1 or 15. How many dates I can keep in the array? How do I create array by the user behavior for the user selected month? I felt that it will be complicated if I start creating an array

Comment: You should elaborate on why disabled dates array won't work for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you want to accomplish something like this:

```
function isAvailable(date) {
  var dt = date.getDate();
  if (dt == 1 || dt == 15) {
    return [true,"",""];
  } else {
    return [false,"",""];
  }
}

$('#some_div').datepicker({ beforeShowDay: isAvailable });
```

A more general solution would be:

```
var dates_avail = [1, 15, 23, 27];
function isAvailable(date) {
  var dt = date.getDate();
  if (dates_avail.indexOf(dt) != -1) {
    return [true,"",""];
  } else {
    return [false,"",""];
  }
}

$('#some_div').datepicker({ beforeShowDay: isAvailable });
```

Or to check specific dates of specific years:

```
var dates_avail = ["1/1/2016", "21/4/2016", "19/3/2016"];
function isAvailable(date) {
  var dt = date.getDate();
  dt += "/" + (date.getMonth()+1);
  dt += "/" + date.getFullYear();
  if (dates_avail.indexOf(dt) != -1) {
    return [true,"",""];
  } else {
    return [false,"",""];
  }
}

$('#some_div').datepicker({ beforeShowDay: isAvailable });
```

Comment: Thanks @mtndesign. Your first solution (with isAvailable function) is what I am looking at. Exactly works. Thanks again :-)

Answer (score 0):

I want to use this function, is this format correct please?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

                    function isAvailable(date) {
                        var dt = date.getDate();
                        if (dt == 1 || dt == 16) {
                            return [true, "", ""];
                        } else {
                            return [false, "", ""];
                        }
                    }
                    $('#date2').datepicker({ beforeShowDay: isAvailable });

            </script>
```